# Install Eclipse plugin from outside Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, plugins

My Eclipse Marketplace/Install New Software links are not working. Is there any other way to install a plugin in Eclipse? Can you please tell me where I can download a plugin independently and install in Eclipse manually?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can install a plugin from an archive.

- In `install new software`
- Click on `Add`
- Under `Location` Click `Archive`

Comment: Benoit I tried it. But each time I am providing a zip or a jar file it  is saying "No software site found at this file /D:/..."

Comment: Which one are you trying to install, any link?

Comment: This is what I am trying to install: http://forge.ow2.org/project/download.php?group_id=23&file_id=19465

Comment: Try by adding this url `http://download.forge.objectweb.org/eclipse-update/` when adding new software.

Comment: It is saying "could not find the site". In fact, this is the issue I am having with all the sites. Hence, I wanted to use some manual ways to install plugins.

Comment: You can only use this method if the software to be installed is set up as a Eclipse 'update site', it can't be used for just a plugin.

Comment: Working here, past the url I gave in the textbox that says `type or select a site`, then click `Add`, then click `Ok` in the popup. It will be pending and then the softwares will appear.

Comment: @RémiBenoit Yes the link you posted is an update site so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way: Some plugins have an *Install* button on the Marketplace website (e.g. [this](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/elysium)) which you can simply drag & drop to Eclipse.

Comment: I am dragging the Install button into Eclipse workspace, but nothing is happening. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have Marketplace Client installed at all? Check it at About > Installation Details > Features.

Comment: Yes, it is installed. Still nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a plugin rather than an install package (also known as an update site) then copy the plugin to the `dropins` folder in the Eclipse install and restart Eclipse.

Comment: Is a plugin a jar file? Can you please give me a link of a plugin? I am finding jar and zip files when trying to find plugins.